# “Read permission” level will not allow users to see the metadata navigation tree

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site, managed-metadata

I have a main publishing site and 5 sub sites, and I define a metadata navigation tree as shown below.

But all the users that have the “Read permission” level will not be able to see this tree as shown below, while “Contributors” can see it.

But the problem is that when I access the “Read permission” level to add the needed permission,, I cannot find any single  permission which is related to view a metadata navigation tree.

Can anyone advice?.
[image]

Comment: Is the pages published and approved ? just a thought

Comment: Yes all the pages will be published automatically (no approval stages are mentioned). and as i mentioned in my original question users which are inside the Contributors and admin groups can see the navigation tree.

Comment: OK, yes I saw you mentioned that but depending on how the library is configured contributor will still be able to see the drafts where readers will not. Have you checked in managed metadata in central admin the permissions section?

Comment: if you are talking about the Metadata service ,, inside its permission section there is only the local farm  account defined. and i do not think i should add the groups to it...

Comment: I think the metadata Nav tree in SharePoint 2013 have a lot of bugs. starting from displaying it as i had to manually reference the NavTree in the page layout  . and now it is being shown to specif user groups only. best regards

Comment: did you fix this issue? i am also having same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that on the navigation tab of the term, you select Simple link or Header. This will fix the issue.[image]